# How to adjust img and ul tags in Header?

Tags: html, css

I have a little bit confusion, i want to put img and ul tag in header and i put it like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
   <div class="container">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#"> Help </a></li>
     <li><a href="../about/about us.html"> About Us </a></li>
    </ul> 
    <div class="img01">
      <img src="images/vfp logo.png" alt="LOGO" height="127" width="177">
    </div><!-- .img01 -->
  </div><!-- .container -->
</div><!-- .header -->
```

**CSS**

```
.header{
    height: 135px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    position:relative;

}

    .header a{
    color:#000;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    float:right;
    padding: 14px 10px;
    position:relative; top:40; right:40;
    margin: 0px 30px 0px 0px;
}

.header li {
    display: inline;

}

.header img01{
    text-align:left;

}
```

The problem is I have adjust ul and li tags, and they are fine for my page, but the img can't move.. and don't know where should i put padding and margin for img?

Comment: img01 is not a valid tag selector. Is img01 the value of the ID or CLASS attribute of the img tag you want to style?

Comment: This a the index code,



</head>
<body>


  <div class="header">
   <div class="container">
  <ul>
 <li><a href="#"> Help </a></li>
 <li><a href="../about/about us.html"> About Us </a> </li>
  </ul>
                    
  <div class="img01">
  <img src="images/vfp logo.png" alt="LOGO" height="127" width="177">
     </div> 
   </div> 
  </div>

Comment: @Flynn.Rider, which index are you talking about?

Comment: it seems `img:nth-of-type(1)` is what you want...

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS as it is now is not valid.

I think you probably want this:

```
.header img{
    text-align:left;

}
```

Or, if you are trying to style a specific img that doesn't have an ID:

```
.header img:nth-of-type(1){
    text-align:left;

}
```

However, if your img tag has an ID, you can just specify it:

```
.header #someID{
    text-align:left;
}
```

**EDIT**
Based on your updated comment, you are trying to style a class named img01, which looks like this:

```
.header .img01 {
    text-align:left;
}
```

You can also style the img specifically:

```
.header .img01>img {
    text-align:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   .header{
        height: 135px;
        background-color: #CCC;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
        position:relative;

    }

    .header > a{
        color:#000;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-weight:bold;
        text-decoration:none;
        float:right;
        padding: 14px 10px;
        position:relative; top:40; right:40;
        margin: 0px 30px 0px 0px;
    }

    .header > li {
        display: inline;
    }

    .header > ul {

    }

    .header > img{
        text-align:left;
        padding: 1em;
        margin: 1em;

    }
```